# Image processing using MATLABR2010a

Tags: matlab

I tried to read an image and display it but i faced an error and i didn't understand it.can any one help me please, note that i use MATLAB R2010a, and the  display below is the type of error.

```
>> imread('tas.jpg');
>> imshow('tas.jpg');
??? Attempt to call constructor image with incorrect letter case.


**Error in ==> basicImageDisplay at 9
hh = image(xdata,ydata,cdata, ...
Error in ==> imshow at 246
  hh = basicImageDisplay(fig_handle,ax_handle,...**
```

Answer (score 3):

```
I = imread('tas.jpg');
imshow(I);
```

The `imread` function reads the file and converts it to a RGB matrix of pixels. This is stored on the variable I. Then, you can call `imshow` passing this RGB matrix as a parameter ;)

**edit** you can call `imshow` with the filename as well, but it's not that useful because it does not return the matrix you will later use for processing. And as the error is thrown only on `imshow`, I'm guessing the `imread` function, for some reason, is working.

If not, just double check if the image is on the actual directory or in a directory on the path, or if it is not corrupted.

Comment: i try it bu i still get the same error!'code'>> I=imread('tas.jpg');
>> imshow(I);
??? Attempt to call constructor image with incorrect letter case.


Error in ==> basicImageDisplay at 9
hh = image(xdata,ydata,cdata, ...

Error in ==> imshow at 246
  hh = basicImageDisplay(fig_handle,ax_handle,...

Comment: try this: I = imread('ngc6543a.jpg); imshow(I);  if it works, the problem is with your jpeg

Comment: I tried some other format of image but I still face the same problem. can this problem be because of my computer???yes the image is in the same directory

Answer (score 0):

This might be the reason (from the below thread):

Reason: "current directory folder name is match with built-in function in matlab library and gives the error - Attempt to call constructor image with incorrect letter case".

Solution: change the folder name with unique name.

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/256922