# matlab image processing.while i running this matlab code error showing as given below.how to correct it?

Tags: image, matlab

while i running this matlab code error showing as given below.how to correct it?

code-

```
clc;

clear all;

close all;

a=imread('gatephoto.jpg');

subplot(3,1,1);

c=imshow(a);
```

error-

```
Attempt to call constructor image with incorrect letter case.


Error in basicImageDisplay (line 23)
hh = image(xdata,ydata,cdata, ...

Error in imshow (line 267)
  hh = basicImageDisplay(fig_handle,ax_handle,...

Error in lab1 (line 6)
c=imshow(a);
```

Comment: Do you have a function named `image` elsewhere?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10043967/image-processing-using-matlabr2010a

Comment: just double check if the image is on the actual directory or in a directory on the path, or if it is not corrupted.

Comment: @halfdreamer - Though the same error, the methods to reproduce the error are not the same.  alexforrence is most likely correct in his assessment on why the OP is experiencing the error.